# How can I find animation nodes in node editor?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I cant find Animation Node in Node Editor in Blender 2.79. I cant reach step which is in the image below. Can you help me? [image]

Comment: Are you sure you installed Animation Nodes correctly? Can you see it in the addons panel?

Comment: After you have installed Animation Nodes, you can view the manual here. https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Scrapbook on Animation Nodes. Mostly screenshots of node works. Links are included.  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-n_R7yN2R-0ZUkj8xZyW5ObWzh_aEEFaRqv0SpC27V8/

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have animation node editor you should activate "animation node" in your preferences/add_ons

you can get it from https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes and install it

when you use object node in node editor, you should assign an existing object to it. you can't create new object with this object node.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to install the animation nodes addon : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes